# Comparing a value with an array under a condition

Tags: matlab, if-statement

Let's we are given a number that we would like to compare it with the whole numbers which are in a column of matrix. For example:

```
value = 210;
A = [
    0.0010   68
    0.0011  277
    0.0011  129
    0.0012   87
    0.0015   78
    0.0016  248
    0.0019  270
    0.0019  133
    0.0022  258
    0.0025  264
    0.0029  255
    0.0030   81
    0.0032  242
    0.0033   27
    0.0036  124];
```

Now, we want to compare `value` with all the numbers in column two under a condition and if it satisfies for **all the numbers** in the second column then do some computations otherwise do some other computations. If it does not hold for one then exit and continue code.
In the example:

```
if abs(value - A(:,2)) > 50 % should be true for all A(:,2)
    do something
else
    do something
```

How could one write it in code?

Comment: `if all(abs(value - A(:,2)) > 50)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. would you please write as a answer.

Comment: I would rather encourage you to read up on [`all`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) and [`logical indexing`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk576-1) and post your findings as an answer on how those two come up and solve this problem.

Comment: In fact, you don't need to worry about `logical indexing` here!

Comment: I think you pretty much already wrote it in your question? Note that `all`, even though I'd also use it for clarity, is [not really necessary](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) ("An `if` expression is true when its result is nonempty and _contains only nonzero elements_")